# How to convert dataset with multiple images from np.array to PIL images

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have an array of shape `(21785, 69, 69)` that I want to convert to PIL images. The images have a mean of 0 and are normalized with a maximum of 1. Furthermore they are grayscale images (as can be seen from the shape). For a single image, I found the solution of:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.fromarray(image.astype('uint8') * 255, 'L')
```

How does this work for a set of images?
Thank you for your help!

Edit:

when I use the whole set I get the error:

```
ValueError: Too many dimensions: 3 > 2.
```

Comment: So you actually have 21,785 images of 69x69 pixels. The `dtype` is currently presumably `float` and the pixel intensities range from [-1,+1]?

Comment: Do you want to save them to disk as 21,785 PNG files, or something else?

Comment: Yes there are 21,785 of size 69x69. The dtype is `float`and the range is from [-1,1] with zero mean. I want to use the images for a convolutional network and apply transformations with torchvision. For this purpose, the torchvisions.transforms requires PIL images.

Answer (score 0):

Untested...

If you multiply your image by 127.5 and add 127.5 to the result, you can make a `uint8` in the range [0,255] which PIL will like:

```
scaled = ((image*127.5)+127.5).astype(np.uint8)
```

Now you can make your first, and subsequent PIL Images like this:

```
PilImage = Image.fromarray(scaled[0,...], 'L')
```